# How to get the id of the json data inserted in the Mongo db collection with node js app on Bluemix

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, ibm-cloud

I had one json data,I want to pass that JSON data in to Mongo db collection.
The json data is,

```
json=
{
"customerdetails" : {
    "organId" : "sample",
    "address" : {
        "addressLine1" : "123213",
        "postcode" : "RG16QX"
    },
    "customerName" : "don",
    "dob" : "sample"
},
"transactiondetails" : {
    "bankDetails" : {
        "accountName" : "john",
        "bankAddress" : "sample"
    },
 "brokerId" : "12345"
  }
  }
```

I want only customerdetails details json part to be stored in one collection.Then I want to get the id of the inserted json(_id":"nFNBY4GN6m6jjpNEY")..Then I want to replace this id in the customer details value and insert this json in another collection.

```
{
"customerdetails" :{ "_id":"nFNBY4GN6m6jjpNEY"},

"transactiondetails" : {
"bankDetails" : {
    "accountName" : "john",
    "bankAddress" : "sample"
},
"brokerId" : "12345"
}
}
```

The code which I am using is

```
var jsondata=JSON.parse(json);
 var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
 mongourl="*******";
 MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function (err, db) {
      console.log("inside mongo client");

   if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
   } else {
var collection = db.collection('customerdetails');
collection.insert(jsondata.customerDetails, {safe:true},function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
      console.log("got error");
   console.log(err);
  } else {
    var collectionid=result._id;
    console.log("*********"+collectionid);
      console.log("collection"+collection);
   console.log('Inserted documents ");
  }
  });
  }
```

But I am unable to insert in to collection..
And also if it gets inserted how can i get the _id of the inserted data from the collection and replace that with the key value and pass the remaining JSON in to another collection..
Can someone suggest any ideas.
By the way Iam using nodeapp and mongodb service on bluemix.
Thanks

Comment: U can get it as result.id. First check the result values in console.. and pick the id.

Comment: result.id is enough

Comment: try to display or console your result

Comment: Thanks ..But the problem is its not going inside the MongoClient and not printing any console.do u see any issue der..I had modified the code

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issue in your code, we know that javascript is case sensitive and you are using `jsondata.customerDetails` while you should use `json.customerdetails` and you must know about `insert` callback function's argument.

You do not need to use `JSON.parse(json);` because your your variable `json` is already object. Here is code

```
var json = {
    "customerdetails" : {
        "organId" : "sample",
        "address" : {
            "addressLine1" : "123213",
            "postcode" : "RG16QX"
        },
        "customerName" : "don",
        "dob" : "sample"
    },
    "transactiondetails" : {
        "bankDetails" : {
            "accountName" : "john",
            "bankAddress" : "sample"
        },
     "brokerId" : "12345"
  }
}

var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var mongourl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/stackoverflow';

MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function (err, db) {
    console.log("inside mongo client");
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        var collection = db.collection('customerdetails');
        collection.insert(json.customerdetails, {safe:true},function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("got error");
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              json.customerdetails = {
                  "_id": result.insertedIds[0]
              }
              console.log("********* Here is updated josn ***************");
              console.log(json)
              console.log('Inserted documents ');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks..Thanks ..But the problem is its not going inside the MongoClient and not printing any console.do u see any issue der..I had modified the code ..

Comment: You may like to copy above code and replace to your code.  I have tested and seems working fine.

Comment: I modified the code in my question..It is not entering inside the MongoClient..If it go inside it ,then your insert logic will work.can u check that modified code

Comment: You did not yet modified code as I suggested. I have updated my code and copy above code and replace to your code and then try

Comment: Yes arif,,I tried ,,but for me here it is not going inside MongoClient

Comment: Have you installed [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/#tutorials) ? You need to make sure `MongoDB` running on your local PC because above code working on my PC

Comment: I don't know more about `Bluemix` but you need to make sure you have installed mongodb and it is running where you are using

Comment: Adding Compose tag to get the attention of the Bluemix db developers.

Comment: @ArifKhan..Its working now after some changes in bluemix,now how can i store that id in the customerDetails key value and insert whole in another collection.Think should use functions for this.This is my actual question

Comment: @HVarma Please see answer once again, I have inserted `_id` in `customerdetails` key( you need to make sure using case sensitive manner)

Comment: @ArifKhan Thats fine what I was telling is now we should modify main json.
json=
{
"customerdetails" : {
      "_id": result.insertedIds[0]},
"transactiondetails" : {
    "bankDetails" : {
        "accountName" : "john",
        "bankAddress" : "sample"
    },
 "brokerId" : "12345"
  }
  }

Replace customerDetails value with the generated id and insert the whole json in another collection

Comment: You are free to modify, update and delete any key of json after insert. What is issue ?

Comment: I think your issue is resolved. You may like to accept this answer and as well upvote this helped you ):

Comment: function replaceByValue( field, customerdata, newvalue ) {
         for( var k = 0; k < jsondata.length; ++k ) {
          if( oldvalue == jsondata[key][field] ) {
            jsondata[k][field] = newvalue ;
           }
        }
    return jsondata;
    }


using this but its not working